# Backbone/Javascript scope. How to access this.el inside .each

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to access `View`'s `el` method  inside `each` iterator of collection. 
This is  mock up of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ASdWU/.
Is it possible?

I need it because I want to iterate over models of collections, create and append their view's to `.el` element (I cannot use jQuery's `$()` because of `has_many` relation where each model has its own collection so their css-id is repeated and I cannot select particular id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the view (`this`) as the third (context) argument to [`.each()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each):

```
_.each([1], function() {
         alert(this.el);
}, this);
```

[Forked fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LHMAq/)

Comment: Might be worth noting that the callback function will get the array element as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable within the scope that the `.each()` function can access: http://jsfiddle.net/ASdWU/1/